# how to add an elemnt with text inside in Javascipt Dom

Tags: javascript

I work currently on my todo list.

I manged to get the text value from my input but i dont now how to add and element with the text value inside the text area. I want to add the text from my input inside the textarea in the undordered list.

Green is the input field and i want to get it from there in the white field[image]

```js
//query select to get button

let btn = document.querySelector('.add');
// selector to selct undorder list inside todotex
const ul = document.querySelector('.list');
//selector for input
const input = document.querySelector('input');

// eventlistner by button clicked

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var txt = input.value;
  let li = document.createElement('li').innerHTML(txt);
  ul.append(li);
});
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="todoheader">TODO List</div>
  <div class="todotext"></div>
  <ul class="list">

  </ul>
  <div class="addtodo">
    <button class="add" type="button"> + </button>
    <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="add todo"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a method, but a property.

Comment: Also input does not need an end tag. Either `<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="add todo" />` or `<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="add todo" />`

Comment: You need also to create the LI before adding the innerHTML - it does not chain: `let li = document.createElement('li'); li.innerHTML = txt;
`

Answer (score -1):

As comment by @CBroe.
Replace `innerHTML(txt);`to `innerHTML = txt;`

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions and especially not if already answered in a comment

Answer (score -1):

`https://jsfiddle.net/Memorynotfound/obhq8x50/`

I found this JSFiddle that might help. Google is your best friend.

This guide explains it:
`https://memorynotfound.com/dynamically-addremove-items-list-javascript/`

```js
function addItem(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
  var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.setAttribute('id',candidate.value);
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(candidate.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
}

function removeItem(){
    var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
  var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
  var item = document.getElementById(candidate.value);
  ul.removeChild(item);
}
```

```html
<ul id="dynamic-list"></ul>

<input type="text" id="candidate"/>
<button onclick="addItem()">add item</button>
<button onclick="removeItem()">remove item</button>
```